# Launch bat with CustomAction

Tags: batch-file, command-line, wix, custom-action

I have my wix file (.wxs) with my CustomAction :

```
...
<CustomAction Id="shellex" Directory="WINDOWSVOLUME" Impersonate="no" ExeCommand="cmd.exe /k &quot;C:\rep\file\script.bat&quot; " Return="asyncNoWait" />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
<Custom Action="shellex" After="InstallFiles" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
...
```

But when i execute my wixinstaller, it's all good except the CustomAction with cmd.exe that opens and informs that "The specified path was not found" but the path is correct.
I don't understand why batch file was not found.

**ADD**
Detail : My .bat was deployed with the installer.

Anyone have a solution ?

**Edit 1 :** 
I tried `ExeCommand="cmd.exe /k cd rep "`
And i have "The specified path was not found"

**Edit 2 :**
I tried `ExeCommand="cmd.exe /k dir /s A:D >out.txt "`
And i see that folder /rep/ doesn't exists at the .bat execution.
/rep/ was created with installer.

The property `After="InstallFiles"` doesn't works ?

Comment: try with  `ExeCommand='cmd.exe /k "C:\rep\file\script.bat"'` - this is still valid xml and without xml escaping of the quotes which can harm the cmd command.

Comment: @npocmaka No, still the same message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.

The solution was to change `After="InstallFiles"` to `After="InstallFinalize"` .

With "InstallFinalize" the CustomAction is executed at the very ending of installation. Before the "shell" couldn't find the batch file because he had not yet been deployed.

Comment: Do you mean "InstallFinalize"

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the current directory got changed as happens by design when a bat file is 'Run as administrator'. Add this to the beginning of your bat file to verify:

```
echo(cd=%cd% & pause
pushd %~dp0
echo(cd=%cd% & pause
```

You may see that the first cd displayed is not what you expected and the second is correct. If that is the case remove the 1st and 3rd lines above. The pushd line sets the CD to the original directory.

Comment: I tried that but i always have the same message "The specified path was not found".  I think that wix want execute my .bat before he deployed.

Comment: Your Edit 1 and Edit 2 examples have a space at the end... just before the ending ". Remove that space.

Comment: Did you see what you expected with the echo(cd=%cd% & pause? Current directory may be set incorrectly by Directory="WINDOWSVOLUME"